# QueryExtender IgnoreCase with Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, case-sensitive, entitydatasource, query-extender

I have a **QueryExtender** control with an **EntityDataSource** as Target (db **Oracle11g**). I've added a Search Expression to it with the property **ComparisonType**="CurrentCultureIgnoreCase".

When I perform the search, it doesn't ignore CaseSensitivity at all.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by CustomExtender to make it lower case